# Java - transferring the readLine mechanism to a JFrame w/ JButton?

Tags: java

I currently am developing a small chat program which works fine as a console application.
It's only working because of a `readLine()` though, because there are some `while(true)` loops. Now I tried to get this into a `JFrame` to have it look more beautiful. What comes now is that of course it is not working.
My question: is there a way to implement that `readLine()` like mechanism in a GUI, i.e. wait for a JButton to be clicked before continuing the loop?
Example:

```
while(true)
   someString = myScanner.readLine();
```

This now in a `JFrame`. Pseudo-code-like-thing:

```
while(true)  
   someString = myButton.wasClicked()
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Java GUI is event-driven. You need to learn about event-driven programming. `while(true)` loop simply should not be done in a GUI.

Comment: You're trying to do some advanced work here -- combine long-running blocking code with an event driven single threaded GUI library -- and so you need to understand the underlying concepts before moving forward. Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for these concepts.